# Find the Work $\oint Pdx+Qdy$ of the $F(x,y)=(−y^2,x^2)$ on the rectangle $x−y=0$,$x−y=1$,$x+y=1$,$x+y=2$ (positive direction)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, greens-theorem

Find the Work $\oint{Pdx+Qdy}$ of the $F(x,y)= (-y^2,x^2)$ on the rectangle (pic)  $x-y=0, x-y=1, x+y=1, x+y=2$
(positive direction)

From Green's theorem: $$\oint{Pdx+Qdy}= \iint{\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}\right) dxdy}$$ Where, $P=-y^2 , Q=x^2 $

Normal to $x$:

$$ \int_{0}^{0.5}{} \int_{1+y}^{1-y}{(2x+2y)dxdy+\int_{0.5}^{1}{} }\int_{y}^{2-y}{(2x+2y)dxdy}  $$

[image]

> My question is: Do I have to add or subtract the second integral (because of the directions of $a$ and $w$ (shown in above pic))?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Notice, divide the region bounded by the lines $x-y=0, x-y=1, x+y=1$ & $x+y=2$ into two parts and consider two horizontal rectangular slabs in these parts and apply proper limits of $x$ & $y$ (as shown in above figure). Add these two double integrals as follows

The first integral must have proper limits of $x$ from $x=1-y$ to $x=1+y$ and $y$ from $y=0$ to $y=0.5$ as follows
$$ \int_{0}^{0.5}{} \int_{\color{blue}{1-y}}^{\color{blue}{1+y}}{(2x+2y)dxdy+\int_{0.5}^{1}{} }\int_{y}^{2-y}{(2x+2y)dxdy}  $$

$$=\color{blue}{-}\int_{0}^{0.5}{} \int_{\color{blue}{1+y}}^{\color{blue}{1-y}}{(2x+2y)dxdy+\int_{0.5}^{1}{} }\int_{y}^{2-y}{(2x+2y)dxdy}  $$
$$=\color{red}{\frac32}$$

Comment: Answer the question, please, if it is not very difficult.

Comment: Well, OP's question is answered. I just pointed out his mistake in integral. Tell me what is missing in my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: OP and you are different persons or one and same? Just interesting.

Comment: I insisted not in vain and I apologize if my questions bothered you, Your answers helped me sort out one question. It does not concern you personally and your answers. On the contrary, I always found them very interesting as this last one . Thanks again and please don’t worry.

Comment: I am sorry. Unfortunately I didn't get your point. You are always welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @HarishChandraRajpoot , I have another one similar question: 

Find the Work of the $F(x,y)=(x^2,xy)$, on the triangle $ y=x+1, y=1-x, y=0 $ (positive direction) 

Using Green's theorem again, why this time using normal to x  I have to type "+" before the integral: $\int_{0}^{1}{} \int_{y-1}^{1-y}{ydxdy} $

pic: https://ibb.co/17JT1mh